# Can a dream from Shaytan resemble one from Allah?

Tags: shaitan, dream

Dreams from Allah have been described as short, clear, on specific topic, and typically dealing with the present and the future. Is it possible for a dream from the Shaytan to resemble one from Allah to the extent that the dreamer will not be able to tell if it was from the Shaytan?

Answer (score -1):

Asalam Alaikum

No, Shaitan/Satan never mimics himself as Allah SWT and Rasoolu Allah Sallahu Allahi Wasalam.. Because Satan is the creation of Allah SWT... He can't become Prophet Muhammad PBUH for the mercy of Allah SWT.. If you meet the person whom said that he is Prophet Muhammad PBUH. Identify him by his beard... He PBUH had 63 white hairs... If you don't wish to meet jinns and Satan... Then recite 3 Quls with Ayatul al Kursi...